# How to modify the DateTimeTickFormatter class?

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

```
import pandas as pd
from math import pi
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure

d = {'col1': [dt(2015, 1, 1), dt(2015, 1, 2), dt(2015, 1, 3)], 'col2': [100, 200, 300]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
p.line(df.col1, df.col2)
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days=f"%m/%d %H:%M",
                                          months="%m/%d %H:%M",
                                          hours="%m/%d %H:%M",
                                          minutes="%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
                                          minsec="%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
                                          seconds="%m/%d %H:%M:%S")

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
show(p)
```

I would like to modify the date time ticker class to allow additional data in tick labels. For example, I would like to see the corresponding data in "col2" whenever bokeh places a tick label such as "1/01 00:00 - 100" or "1/01 12:00". There is no added data on second example since it is not a point in the source. For the second example, an interpolation is also acceptable as the data frequency is high in real data set.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh is actually two separate libraries:

- Bokeh the Python Package
- A JavaScript library BokehJS

Being a web-plotting tool, the Python part of Bokeh is actually just a very thin wrapper that drives the BokehJS component in the browser. All of the actual work an implementation is in BokehJS (written in TypeScript). Accordingly, it's generally not possible to make pure-Python changes or edits or subclasses to Bokeh that would have much or any effect at all.

It is possible to create [custom extensions to Bokeh](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html) by supplying your own Javascript implementation of new Bokeh object subclasses. There is in fact specifically an example of a [custom tick formatter](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions_gallery/ticking.html#userguide-extensions-examples-ticking) at the bottom of that docs page. SO is not a code-writing site or service, but if you attempt to create your own custom extension and get stuck, you can provide the complete code for what you try, and ask specific, pointed questions about how to fix that existing code.